# Traverse checkboxes in an ejGrid

Tags: jquery, grid, syncfusion

I have a grid with checkboxes.  I am trying to figure out that when an button is clicked how to traverse the grid to see which checkboxes are checked.

Grid:

```
    $("#dataGrid").ejGrid({
        dataSource: dataManager,
        allowSelection: false,
        allowFiltering: true,
        allowTextWrap: true,
        allowPaging: true,
        filterSettings: {
            filterType: "excel"
        },
        allowSorting: true,
        toolbarSettings: { showToolbar: true, toolbarItems: ["search"] },
        allowSearching: true,
        columns: [
            { type: 'checkbox', width: 50 },
            { field: "Id", visible: false },
            { field: "RegistarName", headerText: "Registrar" },
            { field: "VoterStatus", headerText: "Voter Status" },
            { field: "strTrainedDate", headerText: "Trained" },
            { field: "strOathDate", headerText: "Oath" },
            { field: "Term", headerText: "Term" },
            { field: "OrganizationTypeName", headerText: "Organization Type" },
            { field: "RegistrarOrganizationName", headerText: "Organization" },
            {
                headerText: "",
                template: '<a href="#" onclick="Edit({{:Id}})">Edit</a>',
                width: 75,
                textAlign: "center"
            },
            {
                headerText: "",
                template: '<a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete")/{{:Id}}" data-name="{{:RegistarName}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">Delete</a>',
                width: 75,
                textAlign: "center"
            },
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We have already discussed about “How to get selected records from all page in multi checkbox feature” in our Syncfusion KnowledgeBase. Refer to the KB link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7624/how-to-get-selected-records-from-all-page-in-multi-checkbox-feature

Otherwise on external button click, we can get the corresponding checked/selected records with getSelectedRecords method of the Grid.
API link: https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejgrid#methods:getselectedrecords

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.